# Passing a parameter to a service installer via installutil

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to write a power shell script to install a service but the service requires an extra command line paramiter passed to it. Im having trouble getting this passed over.

Here is the service installer that uses the parameter;

```
this.serviceInstaller.ServiceName = string.Format("My brill service {0}",this.Context.Parameters["environment"])
```

And I have tried passing the paramiter in two ways;

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe "C:\foo\bar.exe /environment:tomtest"
```

(this gives the error "invalid directory on url")

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe /environment:tomtest "C:\foo\bar.exe"
```

(this just dosent change the service name)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was very close. An equals sign `=` has to be used to assign the value of the parameter (not a colon `:`):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe /environment=tomtest "C:\foo\bar.exe"
```